# Why are there so many Bairds?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

I started playing beast mode today and I noticed  that in every wave - every COG hero was a Baird !! After we stopped laughing so hard from wave 12 (Bairds everywhere), we were wondering - why are there so many Bairds?

Comment: Perhaps they're angry Bairds...

Comment: I imagine this is part of the build up to the release of Gears of War Judgement. IIRC there was a similar event in GoW 2 when GoW 3 was due to be released. However, I have been unable to find any posts on the forums to back this up.

Comment: Oh that might be it... But i havent found anything to confirm this as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unconfirmed:** I am almost positive it was **due to the release of Gears of War Judgement** - as Baird is the main character in that game.   They also increased experience earned per match substantially, while offering the ribbon "Judgement", earned after playing your first match of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't played Gears 3 since the beta, but I'm going to go out on a limb and say the reason you are seeing some many Bairds is that he is the equivalent of a wretch or one of the grunts. Not hard to kill but they are plentiful in the earlier stages of the game type.

Comment: I don't think so as he is a main COG.  The weak ones, like wretches would be the 'stranded'

Comment: oh well, was just a guess, like i said, haven't played Gears since the beta